# Postman is giving me the outputs of this endpoint but my localhost is giving me 400 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Dont worry about the api_key as I am doing this just for practice. Earlier it was showing CORS error so i disabled it in chrome. But now its giving me  GET https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=delis&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972 400 error.

```
function sendRequest () {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=delis&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972",true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {i6LdgRRNDolECGnS0Q7MQf5c3-nNV9rciQdmNy6x0jBFGtBv8DlnCSd2erPEOlKOb6m63MFMj0UzEEINB58fmdZBgy0bW75qfrb4BtRQxZGFcmqczb3vFXjK6G9qYXYx}");
   xhr.onload = function(){
      if(this.status == 200){
         var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         console.log(users)
      }
   }
   xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: usually these problems are from HTTP headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it

```
function sendRequest () {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=delis&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972",true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer i6LdgRRNDolECGnS0Q7MQf5c3-nNV9rciQdmNy6x0jBFGtBv8DlnCSd2erPEOlKOb6m63MFMj0UzEEINB58fmdZBgy0bW75qfrb4BtRQxZGFcmqczb3vFXjK6G9qYXYx");
   xhr.onload = function(){
      if(this.status == 200){
         var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         console.log(users)
      }
   }
   xhr.send(null);
}
```

the `{` and `}` used for *env* and *variable* in postman (or other softwares usually)

in raw http request :

```
GET https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=delis&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer i6LdgRRNDolECGnS0Q7MQf5c3-nNV9rciQdmNy6x0jBFGtBv8DlnCSd2erPEOlKOb6m63MFMj0UzEEINB58fmdZBgy0bW75qfrb4BtRQxZGFcmqczb3vFXjK6G9qYXYx
```

postman have a feature that export requests in different programming language, use it to see efferent ([link](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/))